# The 'length' operator is not allowed to take a parameter as an operand

Tags: derby

Our team recently developed a web project with derby database,then found some errors: ***The 'length' operator is not allowed to take a ? parameter as an operand***.

This is my code:

---

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {           
              Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();//加载驱动
              Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mydb","user","123456");

              String sql = "select * from TB_SYS_MODULE where length(?) > 5";
              PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
              ps.setString(1, "fudengok");
              ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

              while(rs.next()) {
                  System.out.println("MODULE_ID:"+rs.getString(1)+"-----MODULE_NAME:"+rs.getString(2));
              }
            } catch(Exception e){ 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 

    }
}
```

> I have searched official document,LENGTH() function allow a dynamic parameter [enter link description here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/). So asking for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Is "fudengok" the name of a column in the TB_SYS_MODULE table?

If so, why not just use:

```
select * from TB_SYS_MODULE where length(fudengok) > 5
```

Comment: "fudengok" isn't the name of a column,it's just a String .the code above is just a sample testing LENGTH() function is allowing a dynamic parameter in derby or not.You can run this code,and you may get erros like the title

Comment: So, what are you expecting the select statement to do? Return all the rows in the TB_SYS_MODULE table? Return none of them? Return just some of them? If you just want to know whether a Java string is longer than 5 characters, you don't need to use SQL; you can just using the length() method on java.lang.String.

Comment: yeah,we have tryed this way getting the length of String using the length() method on java.lang.String and put it into sql as a dynamic parameter.Now,i just want to know LENGTH() function is allowing a dynamic parameter or not.For example:select * from table_name where length(?) = n,this sql can run successfully?

Comment: It's not a query that I would ever find useful, so I'm kind of drawing a blank on how to give you guidance. If I wanted to find the length of a String, I would never use a SQL statement to do this, I'd just use String.length().Do you run this query against other databases? When do you use it, and what sort of results does it give you?

Comment: yeah,i'd use String.length().